# How to fix a while loop that's only running once?

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate how long until India surpasses China in population. My while loop only executes the first iteration, though.

I have tried setting a while loop to execute within the loop itself, and instead it just became an infinite loop. I have tried indenting the `print` statement within and outside the loop as well.

```
China=1.415
Cgrowth=.39
India=1.354
Igrowth=1.11
count=0
while India<China :
     China += Cgrowth*China
     India += Igrowth*India
     count += 1

print(count)
```

My output always ends in 1.
I did the math, and even after one loop the statement is still true, so why is `print(count)` being rin while the loops conditions are false? I've tried `India*=Igrowth` as well, but all the loops still only run the first time.

Comment: 99.9999% chance you are wrong - simple as that. Publish the numbers

Comment: A [mcve] would include the variables' initial values.

Comment: I don't know what math you did, but after the first iteration the condition is false, so the loop stops.

Answer (score 1):

On the first loop, China = 1.415 & India = 1.354, so the conditional will validate to True and run the loop. This will kick off the following recalculations of the India and China variables.

```
China = 1.415 + .39*1.415
China = 1.415 + .55185
China = 1.96685

India = 1.354 + 1.11*1.354
India = 1.354 + 1.50294
India = 2.85694
```

So, on the second loop, China = 1.96685 & India = 2.85694, so the conditional will not validate to True and will return the count after the first loop, which is 1.

Answer (score 0):

GIGO.

Garbage In. Garbage Out.

```
China=1.415
Cgrowth=.39
India=1.354
Igrowth=1.11

China += Cgrowth*China # = 1.966
India += Igrowth*India # = 2.85
```

So India is not less than China after one iteration.

Some basic debugging - like printing out all the values at the end of the loop would have helped you find that a lot quicker than posting here.

My guess is that the growth values should be percentages and the population values billions? You don't seem to have taken account of any units etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
India = 8
China = 15

Igrowth = 0.1
Cgrowth= 0.05
count = 0
while India<China :
     China += Cgrowth*China
     India += Igrowth*India
     count += 1

print(India, China, count)
```

This code print 30.379986686659283 29.698973991590965 14

in your code

```
China=1.415
Cgrowth=.39
India=1.354
Igrowth=1.11
```

after 1st loop 
China will be 1.96685 ( 1.415 + 1.415*0.39)
India will be 2.85694 ( 1.354 + 1.354 *1.11)